# What are the possible reasons why a web API client request does not get to the API

Tags: .net, api, web-services, asp.net-web-api, request

I have two instances of an app running on IIS. Both apps asynchronously calls a web API hosted on a different server (running as a local service). At a point, requests from just one of the apps stops getting to the API. Just to be sure the API is still reachable from the server where the app is hosted, I initiated calls to the API via Postman, and everything goes fine.

Not too clear as to what the issue is exactly, but I can only think based on my level of understanding, that the app could not get further CPU(IO) resource to push further requests to the API.

While my next move is to use a packet sniffer to see if I can trace the requests on the server, I need help on what exactly has gone wrong, what am I to look out for and possible solutions.

I also would love to know what happens behind the doors when calls like this are made( how IO/ CPU resources are allocated for service/ API calls, what happens when a response is received).

====================Edit / More Info (For clarity)=====================

The client app making the API request is an ASP.NET windows service. There are two copies of the App and each of the instances is running on separate servers (Server 1 and Server 2) as local services. The web API is also an ASP.NET app hosted on a different server as a local service.

API request goes here :

[image: API Call]

Also, none of the client app's instance stops running for any reason, the problem is that requests from Server A (Server B never faces such issue) suddenly stops getting to the API.

Further investigations after using Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/) to trace the request reveals that the API requests actually do not leave the app when this problem starts. However, upon restart of the app's instance in question, the requests are then being sent to the API.

Comment: "While my next move is to use a packet sniffer to see if I can trace the requests on the server, I need help on what exactly has gone wrong, what am I to look out for and possible solutions." - no, do this **first** before asking for ideas because without seeing the TCP stream dump there are simply _too many_ possible causes.

Comment: Alright, thought as much. I will do and provide feedback. Thanks

Comment: I added more info on my question (under the edit section)